# is it possible to change windows 10 home to windows 10 home single language without reinstalling?

Tags: windows-10

i have license key for Windows 10 Home single language in My Laptops but i was downloading the wrong windows edition and It's Windows 10 Home, it makes the license key not available and the problem is. i can't re-download the correct edition due to internet data (i'm about to run out of internet data) so the question is, how can or is it possible to change my windows edition from 10 home to 10 Home single languange, without re-installing or download its edition? thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you sure that the media you have downloaded does not include your edition? Usually at start-up the installer allows you to select the edition to install (unless setup has detected a matching license key in UEFI). If you really have the wrong versions you could just use Windows for the next 30 days and then download the correct version and install it over the current version (upgrade installation).

Comment: @Robert : Sorry i mean it does include the edition (pro and home) i did not know if Home and Home single languange are not the same. Yes i really do have the wrong verion of windows. and i already setup the things like utilities software and drivers i don't wanna do so twice but if there's no way i'll do it after 30 days. but let's say i have the correct edition and i want only change the edition and don't wanna make changes to installed things or stuff, is it possible?

Comment: @Robert : i'm sorry i didnt read the full comments,, okay i get it now, thanks for the comment

Comment: Unfortunately the upgrade installation can get a little bit complicated when "downgrading". Some registry changes may be needed. But as you have run out of internet data this is the only option left.

Comment: You cannot downgrade your Windows  edition. You will have to perform a clean install with installation Media that contains the edition you have a license for. That means downloading an ISO that contains it